# Can pattern recognition be used in control engineering? - Neural networks

Tags: control-theory, least-squares, neural-networks, linear-control, adaptive-control

Assume that we have data who looks like this from a dynamical system $G(s)$ e.g mass-spring-damper system. Where the output is the position of the mass and input is the applied force onto the mass.

[image]

Then we cut the data into several different images:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In this case, we can use arrays of fixed size that contains the data.

**Questions:**

1. Assuming that we have a reference signal that output signal shall follow. Is it possible for us to compute the input signals if we have a neural network model?

Example: If we have a desire reference signal that looks like this [image] and our output signal looks like this [image] What input signal should we use then to make the output signal follows the desire reference signal?

2. Is it possible to compute a neural network model if we have like thousands of different arrays with fixed size that contains data?

Example: What tools should I use? Can I use least squares / pseudo least squares to compute the weights for the neural network?

3. Can neural network be a good controller for heavy nonlinear systems where fuzzy models or recursive adaptive controllers are normally used?

Example: We collect enormous massive data, train a model by using linear algebra and then we implement the weights onto an embedded system?

Comment: You will probably also need some sort of memory, such that the initial conditions and any delay can be modeled as well. I believe there are ways to incorporate this into neural networks.

Comment: Also neural networks are usually "trained" using [stochastic gradient descent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Yes, I have lots of memories. I was thinking about like an array that have the size 10. Then the array will pass into another layer that contains 3...what they are called right now, I don't know. Let's call them rings. So there are 3 rings that describe the error of the reference, the derivative and the delay. Then that layer compute the last layer that have 1 ring and that's going to be the input signal.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I see, least square is used there too. :) I don't think I should dig to deep with this. The more complex it become, the harder it will be to implement.

Comment: With memory I am referring to something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Hmm..I don't know the math and how to apply it. But thanks anyway. I will keep that in the memory.